# dplyr 0.7 is not giving me the results I am looking for

Tags: r, dplyr

Need some expert help as I am learning R.  The below code is supposed to give me top 3 dep_delay desc order group by month and day.  However, it's returning select results with dep_delay desc order.  It's neglecting group_by.  What am I doing wrong?

```
 flights %>% 
 group_by(month, day) %>% 
 select(year,month,day,dep_delay) %>% 
 top_n(3, dep_delay) %>% arrange(desc(dep_delay))
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the `flights` data set? See [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/7264964)

Comment: `flights` is provided by the [`nycflights13`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=nycflights13) package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the code is working, it is giving you the three longest delays for every day in every month.

Check this

```
flights %>% 
group_by(month, day) %>% 
select(year,month,day,dep_delay) %>% 
top_n(3, dep_delay) %>% arrange(month, day, desc(dep_delay))
```

Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you!  Didn't think to add month and day to be part of the sort.